# Private inheritence and constructors

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, visibility

I have following problem:

- want to inherit some class as protected (outside derived class i dont need any member or function from base class)
- want to be able to access base constructor in some way

Here is an example (compile error):

```
class Animal
{
public:
    explicit Animal(void){;}
};

class Dog: private Animal
{
public:
    explicit Dog(void){;}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Dog* pDog1 = new Dog();

    Animal* pDog2 = new Dog();

    return 0;
}
```

How can I solve this?
Thanks!

edit: Let's say that Base class is inherited from some library thus i cant change it.

Comment: what do you mean by "want to be able to access base constructor in some way" ?

Comment: @YeenFei, I think it's a syntactical mistake. The OP means conversion from `Dog*` to `Animal*`; because constructor is accessible anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to reinterpret_cast, you may expose the base class with a method. If one day you decide to use composition instead of inheritance, it won't break your code:

```
class Dog: private Animal
{
public:
    explicit Dog() {}
    Animal * GetAnimal() { return this; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Dog* pDog1 = new Dog();
    Animal * pDog2 = pDog1->GetAnimal();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> want to inherit some class as protected

Then theoretically it should be, `class Dog : protected Animal`.

Now, for any non-`public` inhertiance, `Base *p = new Derived;` is invalid; as `Base*` becomes inaccessible. Without `reinterpret_cast<>` or C-style cast it cannot be done.

I will suggest not to use casts. Ideally, for `private/protected` inheritance, base pointer is not supposed to hold derived pointer in general scope. To solve your problem:

1. Either make the `public` inheritance
2. Change design where the cast from `Dog*` to
   `Animal*` is not needed

Comment: or 3. Use Jems advice :) Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

To correct your compiler error simply do:

```
Animal* pDog2 = reinterpret_cast<Animal*>(new Dog());
```